# How to Make Router a "Proxy Free Router"?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, proxy, wireless-router

I am using a network, which uses proxy server e.g. 1.1.1.9 port  8080.

I have my own router in my office. I want to make it proxy free router. **I just want it to configured like I may connect with the router without entering proxy in browser**. In that way, smartphones would be able to connect to the network, which is not possible for now.

I have explored the router setting but could not come up with any solution. 
Any help would be appreciated. 
This is a TP-LINK Router. **Model No. TL-WR940N/TL-WR941ND**

Comment: Are you connecting your personal router to your work's internet?

Comment: yes. it is sort of personal router. I can configure it.